# Sort uppercase cells separately from lowercase ones

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

Sort uppercase cells separately from lowercase ones

Hi!

I would like to resolve the following:
I want to group cells with mixed content, numbers, lowercase and uppercase words into separate columns so I can sort them separately. Large tables, tens of thousands of cells, so it should be as automated as possible.

There are currently lowercase and uppercase words in a column, I just want to filter out the uppercase letters from them that come irregularly alternating with the lowercase letters one after the other.

Even a good sort would be a solution, for example, to separate the lowercase letters from the uppercase letters with one sort, currently I could only type them in alphabetical order, which is not yet a choice between lowercase and uppercase letters.

E.g:
a <z <A <Z
or
A <Z <a <z
sorting would be the goal instead of sorting into an alphabet that does not pay attention to the current font size.

Now I use OpenOffice Calc (7.0.4.2), but every other solutions are welcome, like online tools or in google sheets.

How could all this be solved?

Thanks in advance for your help. :)

Comment: The apps are different, spamming tags causes the question to be too broad.  Also this probably belongs on SuperUser.com

Comment: Ok, thx for the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `FINDB` in google sheets:

```
=INDEX(SORT({A2:A, IFNA(FINDB(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "^."), 
 JOIN(,CHAR(ROW(50:150)))))}, 2, 1),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, wow, wow! I'm so grateful, player0, you definitely saved me from long hours of manual selection. Nice, thx! For me it seems to be good time to learn more about google sheets, its works just fine.